# Xamarin android app on emulator cannot fetch data from locally hosted asp.net core webapi: operation cancelled

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I am developing an Android app with Xamarin forms that gets its data from a ASP.NET core webapi.
But so far, it seems to stop working at the following line:

`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);`

Below is the code I have so far.

```
var content = "";

var client = new HttpClient();

var url = @"https://10.0.0.2:7294/menu";

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>>(content);
```

I have been searching all over the internet looking for a solution, and I actually find posts that have the same problem, but I can't find any solutions within those posts.

I can browse to the url through the Chrome browser, but in the app, it seemingly tries to get the data from the URL and than it throws the following error after an unspecified amount of time:

`System.OperationCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'`

I believe it is some stupid setting that I have not found yet, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Please let me know if you need more information, as I am at my wits end.

Thanks for the help.

At first I thought it was a threadpool error so I tried working with the ConfigureAwait(false) but that did not change anything. So I tried to simplify the code as much as possible to avoid any of those issues.

I added an exception in the inbound firewall rules for the specific port that I use in my example

I tried to set those android emulator proxy settings and reverted it

I added the permissions INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

I found this link from Microsoft which also did not solve anything:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services

And lastly, I found the following suggestion, but that also did not work:

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```

Comment: You can try copying the URL to the browser of your android device and see if it opens normally.

Comment: Browsing to https://10.0.0.2:7294/menu gives me the desired json result, but it does give me the unsecured http result instead

Comment: `give me the unsecured http result instead` Excuse me, but what does this mean.

Comment: It gives me the desired json result, but not over https, only over http, even though I requested the https.

Comment: try to use Postman to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot. The IP for localhost on the AVD is 10.0.2.2, not 10.0.0.2

Thanks for the help either way.